# Unity UI - Запретить получать объекты,которые находятся за UI

Tags: unity3d

Имеется **2D** игра казуальная мобилка, в которой мышкой можно двигать объекты. Камерой двигать тоже можно. Конечно, имеются UI-элементы(кнопки).

#### Проблема

Если за UI-кнопкой находится объект, который можно двигать, и если нажать на эту кнопку, то захватится объект за ним. Как сделать так,  чтобы нельзя было двигать объект, если он находится за UI-элементом?

#### Мои попытки

В начале пытался использовать интерфейсы разные на нажатие кнопки и отжатие кнопки, чтобы выключать компонент, который отвечает за перетаскивание объекта при нажатии, например, кнопки мыши, но с UI интерфейсы работают некорректно, как например, с обычными gameObject объектами. Затем, в голову пришло добавить коллизию на места где кнопки, то столкнулся с тем, что не могу понять как поставить коллизию в сцене туда где отображается UI-кнопки.

Может есть что нибудь на подобии якорей для Canvas,но для gameObject?

Ссылка на видос проблемы - https://youtu.be/FJpuTfTbBLE

Скрипт на движение камерой

```
 if (Input.touchCount == 1 && _dragContoller.CanMoveCamera && _canMoveFromSlider)
    {
        _touch = Input.GetTouch(0);          

        if (_touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Vector3 movePos = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x + _touch.deltaPosition.x * _speed * -1 * Time.deltaTime,
                transform.position.y + _touch.deltaPosition.y * _speed * -1 * Time.deltaTime,
                transform.position.z);
            Vector3 distance = movePos - transform.position;
            transform.position += distance;
        }
    }     
    transform.position = new Vector3(
 Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, _leftLimit, _rightLimit),  

Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, _bottomLimit, _topLimit),
  transform.localPosition.z);
```

Скрипт переноса объектов

```
 private bool _isDragActive = false;
private Vector2 _screenPosition;
private Vector3 _worldPosition;
private Draggable _lastDragged;
[SerializeField] private bool _canMoveCamera;
[SerializeField] private CustomSlider _slider;
private DragController _selfController;
public bool CanMoveCamera => _canMoveCamera;

private void Awake()
{
    DragController[] controllers = FindObjectsOfType<DragController>();
    if (controllers.Length > 1)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    _selfController = this;
}
private void Start()
{
    _canMoveCamera = true;
    _slider.e_canMoveFromSlider += (bool x) =>{ _selfController.enabled = x; Drop();};
}


private void Update()
{
    if (_isDragActive && (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) || (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)))
    {//Если  перестивание активно и отпущено нажатие,то сброс
        Drop();
        return;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))//fix = раньше было просто if без else
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        _screenPosition = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    }
    else if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        _screenPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    _worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(_screenPosition);
    if (_isDragActive)
    {
        Drag();
    }
    else
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(_worldPosition, Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            Draggable draggable = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Draggable>();
            if (draggable != null)
            {
                _lastDragged = draggable;
                InitDrag();
            }
        }
    }
}
private void InitDrag()
{
    _isDragActive = true;
    _canMoveCamera = false;
}
private void Drag()
{
    _lastDragged.transform.position = new Vector2(_worldPosition.x, _worldPosition.y);
} 

 public   void Drop()
    {
        _isDragActive = false;
        _canMoveCamera = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не было взаимодействие с каким либо `UI` у которого `RaycastTarget ☑`

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
```

---

```
if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() == false) 
{
    //...
}
```